# PowerShell remove regex string with next line

Tags: regex, powershell

This is a sample `.txt` file:

```
Line 1
 LineSub 2
  Line2Sub 3
--
Line 4
 LineSub 5
  Line2Sub 6
```

I want to run the followings but my command do not work:

> removing lines with `--\n` completely, so the next line after that should be `Line 4`

> changing  `LineSub` to `NewLine` (note the following space character before the `LineSub`

These are my commands trying to work but failed:

```
(Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file -Raw) -replace " --\n" | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file
(Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file -Raw) -replace "^--\n" | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file
(Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file -Raw) -replace "[^--]\n" | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file
(Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file -Raw) -replace "^[--]\n" | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file
```

The only one worked is:

```
(Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file -Raw) -replace "--" | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\file
```

which removes `--` but my file looks like this:

```
Line 1
 LineSub2
  Line2Sub 3
(THIS IS AN EMPTY LINE WHICH IS NOT REMOVED)
Line 4
...
```

**Update 1**

My expected output:

```
Line 1
 NewLine2
  Line2Sub 3
Line 4
 NewLine5
  Line2Sub 6
Line 7
 NewLine8
  Line2Sub 9
```

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I updated the questions. I had some mistakes in the sample output. Regarding `regex does not remove new line characters`, I can remove new lines with regex in something like VSCode or with Linux `sed` command in one command, but I don't know that in Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following replacement pattern should be able to accomplish your expected output:

```bash
(Get-Content path\to\file -Raw) -replace '(?m)^-{1,}\r?\n' |
    Set-Content path\to\file
```

If you're sure that the lines to remove always have **2 hyphens**, you can use **`(?m)^-{2}\r?\n`** instead. See https://regex101.com/r/KTQ2ht/1 for regex details.

Worth noting that the pattern above requires the use of `-Raw`, which means that we hold the entire file content in memory before replacing it and writing it back. If you want to take a *streaming* approach to preserve memory, you can use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) with the `-Regex` and `-File` flags, but **we can't read and write the same file in this case**:

```bash
& {
    switch -File path\to\file -Regex {
        '^-{1,}$' { continue }  # skip this line
        Default { $_ }          # else, output it
    }
} | Set-Content path\to\otherFileHere!
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to understand what `(?m)` exactly means. I'm reading samples and examples but I didn't understand it fine. I also forgot that Windows's new lines are CRLF, not LF for `\r`. Is the regex powershell uses different with regex Linux and VSCode use?

Comment: @Saeed `(?m)` is the multi-line flag, see the details in the regex101 I linked, essentially: _Causes `^` and `$` to __match the begin/end of each line__ (not only begin/end of string)_. I'm not sure what you mean by "regex powershell uses different with regex Linux and VSCode use". PowerShell uses .NET Regex Engine, and `\r?\n` is used in this answer so that its compatible with Windows and Linux.

Comment: I think I should read more about the regex to understand it better.

Comment: @Saeed this one is not really hard to understand, _matches any line starting with 1 or more hyphens `-` followed by a new-line_. `-{1,}` could be also just `-+`.

Comment: I understand all given regex values, except `(?m)`. That is what I meant to read better:) I know that others do

Comment: @Saeed so, `-Raw` reads the file as a single multi-line string right? so, if you want to match any line starting with `-` then we need to enable the `(?m)` flag, so that the regex engine understands that we want to have `^` matching all new lines not only the beginning of the string. Hope that makes sense.